# How to force string response on a GET request with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

I've written the following code:

```
$.get('http://example.com/books.json', function (data) {
  // ...
});
```

`books.json` is a list of objects of new books, sometimes jQuery parses the JSON data into object, but sometimes leaves as string (probably because of some international/utf8 issues). In that case I call JSON.parse() myself and get valid JSON object that works.

I've a question therefore - what is the correct way to force JSON.parse when doing a GET request with jQuery? I don't want jQuery to guess if it's JSON data or not. How could I make jQuery think it's string always, and I will always call JSON.parse myself?

Comment: Your code you have posted here is valid and good to go. Does the api.json file get changed?

Comment: @michael Yes it's valid, but the problem is that sometimes `data` is string, but sometimes it's JSON object. Yes, api.json gets changed all the time. I used the wrong filename. It's actually `books.json?period=1day` that gets book changes in library where I work for last day. I will update the question.

Comment: I updated the question now. I don't want jQuery to guess if it's JSON data or not. How could I make jQuery think it's string always, and I will always call JSON.parse myself?

Comment: I updated question title as well as content one more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` takes an optional `dataType` argument, and you can specify `text` to force it to return the data as a plain string.

```
$.get('http://example.com/books.json', function (data) {
  // ...
}, "text");
```

Otherwise, it looks at the `Content-type:` header in the response to determine the datatype.

If you want to **force** a JSON parse, you can specify `json`, or you can use `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using **[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)** instead of `$.get`.

If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL.

Most implementations will specify a success handler:

```
$.getJSON( 'http://example.com/books.json', function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        console.log('key is : '+key+" AND value is :"+val);
    });

});
```

**[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would be the opposite of .getJSON? I want to force string actually and call JSON.parse myself.

Comment: You're welcome, i'm sorry can't understand really what you want to acheive, tell me please if the answer not help and i"ll delete it, thanks.

Comment: @bodacydo Your question says "what is the correct way to force JSON.parse", that's what this answer provides. Now you seem to be asking for the exact opposite.